# Twitter bootstrap image rotating (unwanted)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, rotation

I'm writing a project and I have 3 thumbnails per row.

Each one has this code:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
        <?php foreach($list_pjt as $progetto): ?>
            <?= ($row_close_after_three_thumbs == 0) ? '<div class="row-fluid">' : '' ; ?>
            <li class="span4 pjt-thumb" >
              <div class="thumbnail alert-<?= $status_bg ?>">
                <?php
                    $img_thumb_pjt = ($progetto->img == '' || $progetto->img == '0') ? "img/site_basics/pjt_thumb.jpg" : "upload/$progetto->pjt_table/".$this->session->userdata('user_id')."/$progetto->img" ;
                ?>
                <img src="<?= base_url($img_thumb_pjt) ?>" alt="ALT NAME">
                <div class="caption text-center">
                  <h5><?= (strlen($progetto->pjt_name) > 25) ? substr($progetto->pjt_name, 0, 25).'...' : $progetto->pjt_name ?></h5>
                  <p class="badge badge-inverse"><small><?= $type_name ?></small></p>

                  <p><small><?= $this->lang->line('profile_last_mod') ?>:<br><?= timestamp_to_date($progetto->last_mod, $this->session->userdata('lang')) ?></small></p>
                  <p><small><i class="icon <?= $status_icon ?>"></i> <?= $status_txt ?></small></p>
                <?php if($progetto->completato != 0): ?>
                    <p><a href="<?= base_url('project/showpjt/'.$progetto->id_pjt) ?>" class="btn btn-<?= $btn_color ?> btn-block"><?= $this->lang->line('profile_open') ?></a></p>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p><a href="<?= base_url('project/newpjt/'.$progetto->pjt_table.'/'.$progetto->id_acquisto) ?>" class="btn btn-<?= $btn_color ?> btn-block"><?= $this->lang->line('profile_edit') ?></a></p>
                <?php endif; ?>

                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Some picture, per what I see the ones who are horizontally taken, show up fine (see screenshot on the right) others are rotating (screenshot image one)

This is the screenshot: [Result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/frkx5tp4u3tf6wg/Screenshot%202013-10-03%2012.31.30.png)

Any reason for this? How do I fix it?

As a note, this is the uploaded image (straight...): [Original Picture](http://www.wondermark.it/new/upload/books/1/524D3B2EA673B.jpg)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not Bootstrap, the problem is the image metadata. If you inspect it you'll find:

```
kMDItemOrientation = 1
```

So your iPhone and computer are reading this metadata and correcting orientation before showing the image, but browsers don't. The screenshot shows the image *as it is*, without reading metadata.

Ask Google about removing the image metadata (there are plenty of ways depending on your OS), then *true-rotate* it before uploading and the problem will be solved.